# is there anything special i need to do on my server to run jQuery.getJSON on a bookmarklet?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, getjson

I am making a bookmarklet that requires some user details.

I understood my best options for cross domain communication is either `jQuery.getJSON` or appending a form and iframe to the document and setting the form target to the iframe.

I've decided to start with getJSON as it seems alot less messy however seems i have some problem with it.

Here is what i use for the json call :

```
$.getJSON('http://mydomain.com/bookmarklet_getjson_functions.php', function(data) {
        alert(data);
});
```

here is the php page:

```
echo "{";
echo "item1: ", json_encode($item1), "\n";
echo "item2: ", json_encode($item2), "\n";
echo "item3: ", json_encode($item3), "\n";
echo "}"
```

When i click on the bookmarklet link while Firebug is opened i get:

`GET http://mydomain.com/bookmarklet_getjson_functions.php 200 OK 116ms`

But the alert wont happened.

Any clue ?

Comment: You might need to set the content type in the response headers to "text/json" or "application/json" before you `echo` out the content.

Comment: how will i set the headers before the echo ?

Comment: `header("Content-Type: text/json");`. You might want to try the request with `$.get()` so you can specify an error callback. There might be something else happening here that we can't see.

Comment: I'll try with .get and see how this works out..

Comment: Tried $.get() same exact header no response it seems

Answer (score 2):

Alright - found out what i did wrong after testing several other example - problem was i did not returned callback that jquery produce - it is used as sort of a "password"

So the solution is basically:

```
$.getJSON('http://mydomain.com/bookmarklet_getjson_functions.php?jsoncallback=?', function(data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

The last `?` in `?jsoncallback=?` get replaced automatically with a random function name that is later on used as "password"

so now in my php file i first echo the callback function then `()` and inside parentheses i echo the variable in json format:

```
$toecho = array(
"firstname" => "someone",
"lastname" => "somoene's lastname"

);
//return in JSON format
echo $_GET['jsoncallback'].'('.json_encode($toecho).')';
```

This will echo something like:

`jquery_37328327837823232_3236363({"firstname":"somsomeonee","lastname":"omoene's lastname"})`

Hope that helps someone out there.

Comment: This is called JSONP (the P stands for padding, this is the function around the data). The function name is not a "password", it's just used so the client knows which function to call. You could define, that the function is always called `callback()`, but by passing the name as a parameter, your solution gets more generic.

Comment: so you mean if i set the ? to lets say callback or something alike i could later on echo this instead of the random things?

Comment: If you use jQuery (which I recommend), you should use `jsoncallback=?` and let jQuery handle the function call. It's good practice to let the client decide which name to use.  All I'm saying is, that the callback name is not a secret.

Answer (score 1):

That "php page" is a bit strange. You can try this:

```
header('Content-Type: text/javascript');
echo json_encode(array(
    'item1' => $item1,
    'item2' => $item2,
    'item3' => $item3,
));
exit;
```

You should set the content type for the response and properly encode the data you want to send.
(...testing the response is better with `console.log()` instead `alert()` :)

Comment: No it has nothing to do with the content-Type i've found the solution thanks though.